# ActiveMQ check retries on dashboard

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I have implemented re-delivery policy on activeMQ, but the problem is there is no way to see number of retries for a queue on activeMQ provided dashboard. I want to see the number of attempts before it goes to DLQ queue. I am aware of queue retry mechanism, it will retry for n number of times for a single message after completion or forwarding message to DLQ it will pick another message for processing.

below is my code

```
 _connection.RedeliveryPolicy.InitialRedeliveryDelay = 10000;
 _connection.RedeliveryPolicy.RedeliveryDelay(10000);
 _connection.RedeliveryPolicy.MaximumRedeliveries = 3;
 _connection.RedeliveryPolicy.BackOffMultiplier = false;
 _connection.RedeliveryPolicy.UseExponentialBackOff = false;
```

Please let me know if there is any way to see retries on dashboard?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? Also, what "dashboard" are you using specifically? Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, one important thing to note is if you put a RedeliveryPolicy in your broker config AND your connection configuration, you are duplicating effort. Your message will get `retries=(number of connection retries) * (number of broker retries)`. So in your case, if your connection retries is 3 and your broker RedeliveryPolicy is 3, your message will get retried 9 times! It's recommended that you just set your connection retry policy to none, and let the broker handle re-dispatching so it can redistribute the message about the broker cluster.

I was thinking there was an ActiveMQ header that does what you wanted when a message is retried or delivered, but it's not listed in the documentation and after setting up a broker and DLQ-ing a message on purpose, I don't see any message headers set. This is confirmed looking here: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-broker/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/util/RedeliveryPlugin.java#L181

One could write a small enhancement to the broker to [optionally] increment a redelivery count header at that line, and I'm sure the patch would be welcomed by the community.